# Rearrange int array so that all the negative numbers come before the positivite numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, int

I am trying to write a method which takes an array of `int`s and then rearranges the numbers in the array so that the negative numbers come first. The array does not need to be sorted in any way. The only requirement is that the solution has to be linear and it does not use an extra array.

Input:

```
{1, -5, 6, -4, 8, 9, 4, -2}
```

Output:

```
{-5, -2, -4, 8, 9, 1, 4, 6}
```

Now as a noob in Java and programming in general I am not 100% sure on what is considered a linear solution, but my guess is that it has to be a solution that does not use a loop within a loop.

I currently have an awful solution that I know doesn't work (and I also understand why) but I can't seem to think of any other solution. This task would be easy if I were allowed to use a loop within a loop or an additional array but I am not allowed to.

My code:

```
public static void separateArray(int[] numbers) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = numbers.length-1;
    while(i<j){

        if(numbers[i] > 0){
            int temp;
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = temp;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        }

        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were going to solve this problem yourself, without writing a program, how would you do it?  Can you take that solution and break it down into a series of steps that could form the basis of your program?

Comment: You are actually pretty close. The structure of your code is correct, but your comparison isn't quite right, you have an error in your loop bounds, and your output statement is in the wrong place.

Comment: @scottb I have done that several times but I always come to realize that the solution I just came up with is non-linear. I always end up looping it more than once and its driving me insane!

Comment: how can you perform`i++` when you don't know if the number you just put at `i` is positive or negative?

Comment: @Schytheron How about using recursion.?

Comment: *" I have done that several times but I always come to realize that the solution I just came up with is non-linear."* ... well, when I think about what I would do to order the numbers, I quickly realize that I would do it myself in one pass.  Do you find yourself iterating over the entire array over and over again as you solve this?  So, for my part, I can just articulate the rules I follow when ordering the array ... and then code the algorithm from those rules.

Comment: You can simplify the `ifs`. There are three `if` in your code. The better way is to use `if` and `else` together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to change one line to get it (mostly) working. But you need to change two lines to correctly handle zeroes in the input. I have highlighted both of these minimally necessary changes with "FIXME" comments below:

```
public static void separateArray(int[] numbers) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = numbers.length-1;
    while(i<j){
        if(numbers[i] > 0){ // FIXME: zero is not a "negative number"
            int temp;
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = temp;
        }
        i++; // FIXME: only advance left side if (numbers[i] < 0)
        j--; // FIXME: only decrease right side if (numbers[j] >= 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I did notice though that your code did an unneccessery amount of swapping so I improved it a bit. Check my post edit!

Comment: This program will get failed when input start and end have similar sign like (10,-20,40)

Comment: @muzamil I did not provide the code for the solution. I only marked the original code with comments showing where it needed to be fixed. So you yourself must implement the lines marked as "FIXME". I leave that as an exercise for the student. This is obviously a student's question.

Comment: I don't think after fix me code will provide desire output

Comment: is this logic you built yourself ? or copy from somewhere.

Comment: @muzamilsiddiq I copied the non-working code from the question then added my two fixes in order to answer the question

Comment: Missing a fix: decrease `j` by **1** only when `numbers[j] > 0`, i.e. `if (numbers[j] > 0) j--`. @Schytheron   Example input: `[1, -2, -3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9, -10, -11, -12, 20]`

Comment: @junlin - good catch. I've updated the answer. I did not update the code on ideone yet

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with two pointers, `i` and `j` is a good start.

Think about the loop invariant that you immediately set up (vacuously):

- Elements in the range `0` (inclusive) to `i` (exclusive) are negative;
- Elements in the range `j` (exclusive) to `numbers.length` (exclusive) are non-negative.

Now, you want to be able to move `i` and `j` together until they pass each other, preserving the loop invariant:

- If `i < numbers.length` and `numbers[i] < 0`, you can increase `i` by 1;
- If `j >= 0` and `numbers[j] >= 0`, you can decrease `j` by 1;
- If `i < numbers.length` and `j >= 0`, then `numbers[i] >= 0` and `numbers[j] < 0`. Swap them around.

If you keep applying this strategy until `i == j + 1`, then you end up with the desired situation, that:

- `numbers[a] < 0 for a in [0..i)`
- `numbers[a] >= 0 for a in (j..numbers.length)`, also written as `numbers[a] >= 0 for a in (i-1..numbers.length)`, also written as `numbers[a] >= 0 for a in [i..numbers.length)`.

So, you've partitioned the array so that all negative numbers are on the left of the `i`-th element, and all non-negative numbers are at or to the right of the `i`-th element.

Hopefully, this algorithm should be easy to follow, and thus to implement.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works but I picked Patrick Parker's solution simply because it was a easier fix... sorry ;(

Comment: No problem. I didn't want to give you code, because I thought it was better to show how to reason about it.

Answer (score 1):

A linear solution is a solution with a [run-time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) Big-Oh(n) also noted as O(n), in other words, you have to loop through the whole array only once. To sort in linear time you can try one of the following sorting algorithms:

- [Pigeonhole sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort)
- [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)
- [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

Comment: All of those sorting algorithms seem to require an additional array (which I am not allowed to do). I know that loops within loops are not considered linear, but is a solution considered linear if it CONTAINS more than one loop? For example I execute a second for loop after my first one is finished. In my mind it seems to be linear because the complexity is just 2*n (if n is the amount of elements in your array).

Comment: Yes as long as they are not nested loops, you can do that. The complexity will be n+n+n+..+n and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works only if all the negative numbers are located in the right half side and the positives in the left half. For example, your code swaps 6 with 9 which both are positives. So, it depends on the order of your the array elements. As scottb said, try do it by your hands first then you will notice where you did wrong. Moreover, print your array out of the while

Answer (score 0):

```
//Move positive number left and negative number right side

public class ArrangeArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { -2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // even
            if (arr[i] < 0) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    if (arr[j] > 0) {
                        arr[j] = arr[i] + arr[j];
                        arr[i] = arr[j] - arr[i];
                        arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple program it will help you. In this program i have take temp array and perform number of item iteration. In that i have start fill positive value from right and negative from left.

```
 public static void rearrangePositiveAndNegativeValues() {
        int[] a = {10,-2,-5,5,-8};
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        int i = 0, j = a.length -1;

        for (int k = 0; k < a.length ; k++) {
            if (a[k] > 0) {
                b[j--] = a[k];
            } else {
                b[i++] = a[k];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Rearranged Values : ");
        printArray(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package ArrayProgramming;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RearrangingpossitiveNegative {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr= {-1,3,4,5,-6,6,8,9,-4};
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(arr[i]>0) {
                al.add(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if(arr[i]<0) {
                al.add(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from array import *
size = int(input())
arr = (array('i' , list(map(int, input().split()))))
negarr = array('i')
posarr = array('i')
for i in arr:
    if i>=0:
        posarr.append(i)
    else:
        negarr.append(i)

print(*(negarr+posarr))
```

we can also do it by creating two new arrays and adding elements into them as per given condition. later joining both of them to produce final result.